# Generics of Class object

Tags: java, generics

```
public class EnumTest<Integer> {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {

      final Class<? extends String> aClass = (Class<? extends String>) Class
          .forName("java.lang.Integer");
    }
}
```

Above code compiles and runs without error. Why the type information is lost in the Class object of Integer? Is it because of type-erasure?

Comment: Yes, the type information is lost or "type erased".

Answer (score 3):

generics are almost entirely a compile-time show; most of it disappears once we're running java code.

The method `Class.forName(String className)` returns a `Class<?>` - this should be obvious: The method, at compile time (i.e. when it was written) obviously does not know what kind of class you are going to load with it; you can load anything, that is the point. The compiler certainly isn't going to go: Ah, I see a string literal here, I can ascertain at write/compile time that surely in this case, this method would return the `Integer.class` instance, therefore, I ought to say that the expression `Class.forName("java.lang.Integer")` should be interpreted as being of type `Class<Integer>`. If this is confusing, let me know.

Thus, the expression `Class.forName("java.lang.Integer")` is of type `Class<?>`. Sure, if you RAN that code, it's `Integer.class`, but that's okay: `Integer.class` is an instance which is type-compatible with `Class<?>`, in other words, `Class<?> c = Integer.class;` is valid java code.

Next, you cast it. cast is a dangerous word: It is the name of a syntactical construct, but this construct is used for 3 **completely** unrelated jobs in java. Guns, Grandmas, and Apples.

1. transformation. If the thing in the parens is a primitive, a cast operator transforms data. `int x = (int) 5.5;` is an example. If the thing in the parens is not a primitive, this isn't what's happening, and no transformation could possibly occur.
2. type check. If the thing in the parens is a non-primitive, then all you are doing is asking for a type check: IF the expression following the parenthesis is type-compatible with the thing inside the parens, the operation does nothing other than inform the compiler about what type it is. At runtime nothing changes. No transformation is made. If the expression is not type compatible, then a `ClassCastException` results.
3. type assertion. Any generics in the parens is not checked at all, because at runtime the runtime has no idea how to do what you're asking of it. The notion `Class<? extends String>` more or less *does not exist* at runtime, only the concept `Class` (without generics) exists. This is why such an assertion ALWAYS results in a compile time warning: The code is compiled with the presumption that you know what you are doing, and if you say that the expression is what you say it is, I guess so then. If it turns out it isn't, 'weird stuff' happens (generally, the 'weird stuff' is `ClassCastException`s thrown from lines that don't have any casts on them, that's the weird stuff that happens).

Just to make it crystal clear: **Unless the type in the parentheses is primitive, a cast operation does not convert anything!**

So, in:

```
(Class<? extends String>) x;
```

you are combining #2 and #3: You are injecting a runtime typecheck: if x an instance of java.lang.Class, do nothing. Otherwise, throw a CCE. Then, assert (so, at runtime check nothing; no bytecode is generated whatsoever, it's SOLELY a comment that the compiler understands) that the generics fits `<? extends String>`. Which here is non-sensical (us humans can trivially see this assertion is wrong), but that's the point of type assertions: You are explicitly telling the compiler: Nevermind your skills at determining types, do what I tell you!